# The best std::ostream to get bytes from stream - Windows

Tags: c++, std, ostream

On Windows, I am using `TIFFStreamOpen(const char*, std::ostream *);` from libtiff and passing `std::ostringstream` to it for getting data. But I think that is not the fastest way to get bytes, because there are many conversions and data copying:

```
std::ostringstream output_TIFF_stream;
TIFF* ofo = TIFFStreamOpen("MemTIFF", &output_TIFF_stream); 
...
TIFFClose(ofo);

auto str = output_TIFF_stream.str();
unsigned char* chars = (unsigned char*)str.c_str();
```

Is there a better way of directly getting `unsigned char*` data?

Comment: Sure, there usually are several operating system-dependent ways of doing that. Check the programming manuals for your operating system for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have edited my question. Platform is Windows.